# EXCEL -> VISUAL BASIC | If there is no false in the cell then turn off the F9 key

Tags: excel

What to do to: If there is no false in the cell then turn off the F9 key in EXCEL (in Visual Basic).

I wrote something like this:

```
Sub Simple_If()
    If Range("R35").Value = "FAŁSZ" Then
Else
    Application.OnKey "{F9}", ""
End If
```

End Sub

But it turns off this key for me right away..

Comment: Excel treats the Boolean literal `FALSE` (or `FAŁSZ` in your localisation) as not equal to the string `"FALSE"`/`"FAŁSZ"`. Does your code behave any differently if you compare the value of R35 with the constant `vbFalse`?

Comment: Unfortunately not